# Nginx Bad Gateway 502 when accessing istio-envoy deployed on kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, istio

My web application is running on One Server and two worker nodes

my nginx config file is

server {

```
listen ip-address:80 ;

      server_name subdomain.domain.com;
    server_name www.subdomain.domain.com;
    server_name ipv4.subdomain.domain.com;

location / {
proxy_pass http://ip-address:32038/;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

proxy_http_version 1.1;


  fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
}
```

}

server {

```
    listen ip-address:443 ssl http2;  

    server_name subdomain.domain.com;
    server_name www.subdomain.domain.com;
    server_name ipv4.subdomain.domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /opt/psa/var/certificates/scf83NyxP;
    ssl_certificate_key /opt/psa/var/certificates/scf83NyxP;
    ssl_client_certificate /opt/psa/var/certificates/scfrr8L8y;

    proxy_read_timeout 60;

    location / {
      proxy_pass https://ip-address:30588/;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
```

}

my website on http://subdomain.mydomain.com is running fine . but when i use https://subdomain.mydomain.com it displays bad gateway error page server by nginx

through ssh when i run following command everything works fine

### For http

curl -v -HHost:subdomain.mydomain.com http://ip-address:32038

curl -v subdomain.mydomain.com

### For https

curl -v -HHost:subdomain.mydomain.com https://subdomain.mydomain.com:30588

### From server node  SSH

curl -v -HHost:subdomain.mydomain.com --resolve subdomain.mydomain.com:30588:ip-address --cacert /opt/psa/var/certificates/scf83NyxP https://subdomain.mydomain.com:30588

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you curl http://ip-address:32038/ from the host? Http, not https. 502 would usually mean nginx cannot contact proxy_pass address. Do nginx logs help?

Comment: following error is found in nginx log file


*1 peer closed connection in SSL handshake (104: Connection reset by peer) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: workernode-ip, server: subdomain.mydomain.com, request: "HEAD / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://ip-address:30588/", host: "subdomain.mydomain.com"

Comment: Perhaps proxy_pass should be to http, not https. Normally nginx would terminate the ssl, and then call backend via http.

Comment: yes it is terminating  ssl and calling backend . is it default behaviour of nginx or is there any workaround

Comment: Because the backend apparently also needs to be called via https, then you need to use the correct hostname in proxy_pass. Nginx is essentially making another https connection directly to the backend, and therefore hostname has to match the ssl certificate's common name.

Comment: Usually you would have the backend just using http, and then have nginx doing all the SSL bit. It's generally unnescessary to encrypt the connection between nginx and backend, as this connection happens on the same host, or at least within the same network. It becomes more complicated when the backend itself needs to be called via https.

Comment: i agree with you . but in above context can we proxy ssl certificate too so when backend is being accessed it has domain name , and certificated already in headers. as per my understanding at the moment it is  simple tls communication but i think mutual tls is possible too. i may be wrong about these simple and mutual communication or overthinking but can you please confirm if it is possible? then can you please guide me toward right direction .

Comment: Certainly backend can be ssl also. You would just need to ensure the proxy_pass uses the correct domain name, not the IP address, otherwise the SSL certificate common name will not match, and the requests will fail.

Comment: after configuring proxy_pass and passing ssl certificate it works fine . problem was at istio end it was not confiugred with proper certificates . 
can you please have a look on this problem too 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60655838/kubernets-youre-speaking-plain-http-to-an-ssl-enabled-server-port

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about the backend service, I would guess that perhaps it is not equiped for HTTPS. You may simply need to change this line...

```
proxy_pass https://ip-address:30588/;
```

to...

```
proxy_pass http://ip-address:30588/;
```

If the backend service does in-fact need to be called by https (unusual), then we would need to see how that service in configured, as the nginx error suggests that it is not correctly processing the SSL connection.

Comment: i changed my configuration file as you suggested. but still same error. thanks for looking into this problem.  https://ip-address:30588 seems to be properly configures as when i run following command on master node's terminal i can still see my website result 

curl -v -HHost:subdomain.mydomain.com --resolve subdomain.mydomain.com:30588:ip-address --cacert /opt/psa/var/certificates/scf83NyxP https://subdomain.mydomain.com:30588

Comment: If the service on port 30588 is https, then the proxy_pass config will need to change to use the correct domain name.

Answer (score -1):

502 Bad Gateway in Nginx commonly occurs when Nginx runs as a reverse proxy, and is unable to connect to backend services. This can be due to service crashes, network errors, configuration issues, and more. How do we pinpoint the issue? We need to look at what is returning an invalid response to nginx.
Assuming nginx errored because of configuration issues ---
I have run into a `502 Bad Gateway - nginx` simply because I had inconsistencies with white space on my config file.

Probably the result of copy/pasting your config file code here, but there are spacing inconsistencies that could trigger a parsing fail for the file.
i.e. My `502 bad gateway - nginx` error was solved by deleting a space that I had accidentally added in front of a line in the config file.