# You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port in Kubernetes

Tags: networking, kubernetes, istio

My  Gateway file is as

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: my-gateway-secure
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      serverCertificate: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.crt
      privateKey: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.key
      #caCertificates: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-ca-certs/kbundle.crt
    hosts:
    - "*"

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-gateway-service-secure
  namespace:myapp
spec:
  hosts:
  - "sub.domaincom"
  gateways:
  - my-gateway-secure
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: my-mono
        port:
          number: 443
          protocol: TCP
```

and my service file is

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-mono
  namespace: myapp
  labels:
    tier: backend
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-mono
    tier: backend
  ports:
    - port: 443
      name: https
      protocol: TCP
```

Deployment file is as

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-mono
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-mono
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-mono
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-mono
        image: myapacheimage
        imagePullPolicy: Never   
        ports:  
        - containerPort: 443
```

when i access my service using gateway it says

```
Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.
Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) Server at 10.0.159.77 Port 443
```

i can confirm that apache is only listening on 443 and is properly configured

Comment: using https in the url?

Comment: yes i am accessing with https

Comment: Should protocol: TCP be HTTPS?

Comment: 10.0.159.77 is IP of what?

Comment: in service declaration it is not allowed and in service declaration for gateway it doesnt display any different result.

Comment: it is ip address of pod running my-mono application

Comment: can you provide the pod yaml

Comment: yes pods are being generated using deployment file. and has been added in question

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration uses the `TLS` termination on istio gateway. So the `HTTPS` traffic entering the istio ingress is decrypted to plain `HTTP` traffic before reaching Your service endpoint.

---

To fix this You need to configure `HTTPS` ingress access to an `HTTPS` service, i.e., configure an ingress gateway to perform `SNI` passthrough, instead of `TLS` termination on incoming requests.

You can find an example of Ingress Gateway without `TLS` Termination in istio documentation guide [here](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-sni-passthrough/).

---

Your `Gateway` and `VirtualService` should look something like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: my-gateway-secure
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: PASSTHROUGH
    hosts:
    - "*"

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: my-gateway-service-secure
  namespace:myapp
spec:
  hosts:
  - "sub.domaincom"
  gateways:
  - my-gateway-secure
  tls:
  - match:
    - port: 443
      sni_hosts:
      - "sub.domaincom"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: my-mono
        port:
          number: 443
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Best Answer. thanks alot i figured it out. but i had some confusion about hosts value and sni_hosts. your answer helped me to  fix it completely. thanks alot.